# How can I know the index of duplicated text from a selectedtext?

Tags: c#

Lets say, the selected text in a richbox is "JK".

However, "JK" exist more than 1 time in the string. I use the mouse to select the 2nd one.

By IndexOf to search, the index always known as the first one.

How to let the index correctly reflecting I have selected the 2nd "JK" but not the others?

```
richTextBox1.Text = "VBDJKLEDLJKENJKODS";
int index = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(richTextBox1.SelectedText);
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish, but IndexOf is overloaded, and can take another argument that tells it to start searching from that point forward. IE, if you don't specify the 2nd argument, the starting point is index 0, but you could say set it IndexOf(text, 100) and it would start and index 100 and go forward.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_TextBoxBase_SelectionStart `SelectionStart` (In other words, you are attacking the problem the wrong way around)

Comment: Also, you might look at using a RegEx. You could have it find all instances of what you are searching for using Matches (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=net-5.0) then grab the 2nd element in the returned collection.

Comment: @B.O.B. It appears the OP wants to get the index of the selected text rather than the index of the nth occurrence of a given substring. The former is much simpler as indicated by mjwills.

Comment: @mjwills Ah yes. I think completely misunderstood what they were asking for. To user12642222: SelectedText does give you the text that is currently selected, but SelectionStart tells you the exact index where the selected text starts, and SelectionLength tells you the length of the selection.

Comment: my case is the different user will randomly select the second "JK" or the third "JK". I need to let the program to recognize which "JK" they are selecting but not hard code to set the index position

Comment: @user1264222 There's no hardcoding involved here. `SelecttionStart` will give you exactly what you're asking for (have you tried it?) - Additionally, if needed, you can confirm that what the user has selected is "JK" by checking `SelectedText`.

Comment: I strongly suggest you actually click the link I suggested and read it.

Comment: I am misunderstanding the SelectionStart function, I solved simply now. Thank you guys help! :)